# .NET - Remove all listener event handlers from a object

Tags: .net, events, handlers

I have a objectRaiser which can publish events, for example the event "PropertyChanged".
I have too another objectListener, which listen the raised events from first objectRaiser.

How I can remove the event handlers listeneds by objectListener from objectRaiser instance?

I need repeat something important: the event handlers for remove is from objectListener. Don't works for me remove all publications from objectRaiser. I look that in another questions but don't seems a solution for my problem.

Regards and many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From inside `objectRaiser`:

```
MyEvent = null;
```

From outside: you can't, because you don't have access to the delegate that stores the handlers. You could however add a public `ClearHandlers()` method in `objectRaiser`, and call it from wherever you want.

Comment: Based on the question, I think the desire is to remove all of the delegates for a specific subscriber, not all of then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after ... but in the code below, we can use `Reflection` to remove handlers from the instance of the `ObjectRaiser` contained in the `ObjectListener`:

```
namespace ObjectEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        private class ObjectRaiser
        {
            public event EventHandler PropertyChange;

            private string name;
            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return name;
                }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                    PropertyChange(this, new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        private class ObjectListener
        {
            private ObjectRaiser or;

            public ObjectListener(ObjectRaiser or)
            {
                this.or = or;
                or.PropertyChange += new EventHandler(PropertyChange);
            }

            public void PropertyChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm listening!");
            }

            public void RemoveHandlers()
            {
                var lfi = or.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach(var fi in lfi)
                {
                    var eh = fi.GetValue(or) as EventHandler;
                    if (eh != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var del in eh.GetInvocationList())
                        {
                            foreach (var ev in or.GetType().GetEvents())
                            {
                                ev.GetRemoveMethod().Invoke(or, new object[] { del });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var or = new ObjectRaiser();
            var ol = new ObjectListener(or);

            //This will raise the event
            or.Name = "New Name";
            ol.RemoveHandlers();
            //This will throw an exception because the event has no handler associated
            or.Name = "Weird Name";

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this is a very simple example and would certainly require significant modifications for real-world use.

Comment: That code seems delete all active handlers of his event "PropertyChange" from all listeners, but we want delete all handlers ONLY from a concrete objectListener instance.